# Having both C++ and c# plugins for SonarQube causes error on SQL Server

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

With the latest version of SonarCube installed on SQL Express 2014 I get an error when I add the C++ Plugin after the C# Plugin has been installed.

*Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.rules' with unique index 'rules_repo_key'. The duplicate key value is (c-cppcheck, uninitvar).*
*-[Expert from Sonar.log](http://nkdalm.net/1OcRQ14)*

There is very little Googlable support and it looks like it only affects SQL Server so much be a bug in the schema for SonarQube in SQL Server.

Has anyone figured out a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only difference between some of the rules in the C++ plugin is the case of the key. SQL Server must be set to a Case and Accent sensitive collation (which is not the default).

See the C++ plugin FAQ:
  http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5312239

and the SonarQube server requirements:
  http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements